# Discord Bot Automatic Bulkdelete Issue

Tags: javascript, discord

I am setting up a Discord bot that will delete all messages in a specific text channel in an Interval of 15 minutes but the messages won't delete.

```js
Client.on("message", async function(message) {
    if(message.channel.id != "506258018032418817") return;
    setInterval (function () {
        var Trash = message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 100 }).then(
        message.channel.bulkDelete(Trash));
      }, 900000); 
});
```

Comment: do you have a link to the Discord API by chance? also is there a reason you need to make the function `async` if you are not using `await`? You also are missing a `.` before the `then()` so I'm not sure how this is working. Any console errors?

Comment: No Error Showing

Comment: @aug If you click on the [discord] tag and then click "Learn more..." you'll find [a link to the Discord API](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro).  This works for most tags.

Comment: @aug Oh, but that's the wrong link in this case.  You'll want the [Discord.JS documentation, not the Discord API](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to access the `Trash` variable, but it doesn't contain what you think it does.  `Trash` is being assigned [the Promise that represents the end result of the function chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

You should take the result being passed into `then()` and use that as a parameter to your `bulkDelete()` call.

```js
Client.on("message", async function(message) {
    if(message.channel.id != "506258018032418817") return;
    setInterval (function () {
        message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 100 }).then(
           function(deleteThese) { message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteThese); })
      }, 900000); 
});
```

Keep in mind, the logic for this function is not sound.  The pseudo-code goes like this:

```
- whenever a message is sent to this specific channel
  - queue up a timer to happen in 15 minutes
- after 15 minutes, delete 100 messages from the channel
```

Consider what happens if this happens

```
1:00 Paul talks in channel
--- (timer 1 is started)
1:01 Elizabeth responds
--- (timer 2 is started)
... < time passes > ...
1:14 Charles says something in the channel
... < timer 1 triggers; room is wiped > ...
1:15 Diane says something in response to Charles' deleted message
... < timer 2 triggers; room is wiped > ...
1:16 Charles asks Diane to repeat what she just said
```

You might want to change your approach to pass a time in your `fetchMessages()` call so it only deletes messages that are 15 minutes old or older.